# Counting words using javascript - Postman test

Tags: javascript, html, api, count, postman

Hello I am a newbie in API, postman etc. and got some task which I cannot go through.

I need to create test in postman which will check if body text contains 2 words 'Black'.

Body text: ['Green Snake', 'Black Cow', 'Blue Bird', 'Black Cat', 'Yellow Cow']

My code:

```
var colour = "Black"
tests["Body cointains string: " + colour] = responseBody.has(colourCount=2);
```

Could someone help me to solve this?

Comment: Lots of the answers here don’t actually help you with your question - they mainly tell you how you can do what you’re trying to achieve, rather than show you how to create a Postman test for it. If you post the actual response body text, how you see it in Postman, I can post a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an array called bodyText and want to count how many times the array contains the word "Black", you could try this:

```js
var bodyText = ["Black cat", "blue dog", "black bird"];
var count = (bodyText.join("").match(/black/ig) || []).length
console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you need something like this:

```js
 var color = "Black";
 var body_text=['Green Snake', 'Black Cow', 'Blue Bird', 'Black Cat', 'Yellow Cow'];
 var found = body_text.filter(phrase => phrase.match(color))
 console.log("Found ",found.length, " instances with ", color)
```

PS: comment, if you feel this needs some more functionality.

Comment: Might want to throw `found.length` in there for clarity.

Comment: Done that. Thanks for fast review

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array `bodyText`, you could do something like this:

```
let words = [];
let duplicateWords = [];
bodyText.forEach(i => {
    const isplit = i.split(" ");
    isplit.forEach(word => { 
        if (words.find(word)) duplicateWords.push(word)
        else words.push(word)
    })
});
```

After running this, the array `duplicateWords` will contain all words that appear more than once.